# Algorithm to Group All the Cycles Together

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a lot of cycles ( indicated by numeric values, for example, `1-2-3-4` corresponds to a cycle, with 4 edges, edge `1` is `{1:2}`, edge `2` is `{2:3}`, edge `3` is `{3,4}`, edge `4` is `{4,1}`, and so on).

A cycle is said to be connected to another cycle if they share one and only one edge.

For example, let's say I have two cycles `1-2-3-4` and `5-6-7-8`, then there are two cycle groups because these two cycles are not connecting to each other. If I have two cycles `1-2-3-4` and `3-4-5-6`, then I have only one cycle group because these two cycles share the same edge.

The figure below should be able to illustrate my point:

[alt text http://lh5.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SuBhd07xbWI/AAAAAAAAFMs/9OlMhN8uzzQ/s640/mst.jpg](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SuBhd07xbWI/AAAAAAAAFMs/9OlMhN8uzzQ/s640/mst.jpg)

The `R1`, `R2` to `R7` are what I call "cycle". In the above figure, there is only one cycle group encompassing all the `R1` to `R7`.

What is the most efficient way to find all the cycle groups?

Comment: How is your input given? Like in your examples or are you given a graph or something like that?

Comment: This question may be better suited to Math Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish, that might give a clue to why you call it "cycles" and why it has "edges", and what it all means.

Comment: This is definitely not for Math Overflow. As far as I understand this is either a graph algorithm problem or a string matching problem, depending on how the input is given.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The number of cycle groups? The edges/vertices within the cycle groups? Or a full list of cycles within each cycle group?
There is no efficient way to find the full list of cycles (the list may be exponentially large), but for the other questions there might be reasonably fast algorithms.

Comment: Are those input edges directed or bidirectional?

Comment: @John: MathOverflow is for research-level questions (see its faq). If you're not an academic, or otherwise studying at a post-graduate level, then you should not be asking questions on it. It might be nice to have a "Stack Overflow, but for mathematics", but MathOverflow is not that.

Comment: Are the edges directed or undirected?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm looking for a full list of cycles within each cycle group

Comment: @Mark, the edges are undirected

Comment: @IVlad, my input is given in terms of a list of cycles

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Note that in your example you have one more cycle (R8) on the perimeter of the shape that you have forgotten to label. It is connected to R1, R2, R4 and R6 by a single edge.

Comment: You say "cycle", but you've actually picked out the (non-infinite) faces of a planar graph. Is your graph in general planar?

Comment: @algo, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find all the cycles in the graph and label them for example A, B, C, etc. Now make a new graph where each cycle found in the graph is converted to a single node in the new graph. Join the nodes with an edge in the new graph if the corresponding cycles are "connected" in the old graph, using your (rather unusual) definition of connected.

The number of "cycle groups" is then the number of [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) in the new graph.

Comment: @Thanks Mark, but is there anyway to retrieve back all the cycles inside each and every cycle group?

Comment: @Mark, also I question is asking about how to tell if cycles are connected, but in your answer you say that I need to join the nodes, can be more explicitly about this?

Comment: @Ngu: I'll leave the detecting cycles part to someone else. To determine if two cycles are connected, count the number of edges they share. Once you have detected the cycles then you can create a new graph, G'. In your example G' would contain 7 nodes, one for each cycle that you have detected. Call these new nodes R1,R2,...,R7. If two cycles are connected then create an edge between them in G'. R1 should have an edge to R6 and R7. R2 should have an edge to R3 and R7, etc... Count the connected components of that graph using any standard algorithm from Wikipedia - the answer is 1.

Comment: now it's clearer, do you have the reference on connected component counting from Wiki? Can share?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithms

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that this isn't the most efficient way, but this would be my initial attempt:

First exchange edges with vertices: So for your example cycles `1-2-3-4`, `3-4-5-6` and `5-6-7-8`, you'll need:

```
"12" => "A"
"23" => "B"
"34" => "C"
"45" => "D"
"56" => "E"
"67" => "F"
"78" => "G"
"41" => "H"
"63" => "I"
"85" => "J"
```

This gives you up to (v*(v-1))/2 vertices, but okay - it may still be good enough for a O(v^2) algorithm.

Then represent the cycles as bitfields:
"1-2-3-4" becomes ABCH

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
1110000100
```

and "3-4-5-6" becomes CDEI

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
0011100010
```

So they have exactly one bit in common, which means that in the original graph, they had exactly one edge in common. This could be checked either bit by bit with O(v^2), or with binary search (first check by ANDing, if they have any bit in common, then check ANDing the first half of bits etc.)

Comment: Don't think your solution works,  what about if two cycles that dont connect directly, not nevertheless still belong to the same cycle group?

Comment: @Ngu: My intention was to test two cycles first, and combine them into one, if they're connected (combining can be done easily by an OR operation). Then continue with the next cycle. I hope I understand grouping correctly, as it is used here!

Comment: If you want to improve performance, you could also try experimenting with testing three or four cycles at once by ANDing them (depending on how likely it is, that cycles are in one group, you could tweak the performance this way). Then "drill down" to pairs of cycles only, if a match occurred. It may even be possible to start with ANDing one half of the cycles and "drilling" down recursively...